# Поясните фрагмент кода ContentProvider'a в методе insert()

Tags: android, contentprovider

В блоке кода, где проверяются переданные значение values на наличие вставляемых данных для определенных столбцов, в случае их отсутствия, зачем помещать пустое значение? Если в базе данных столбцы имеют какое-либо значение по умолчанию, то эти строчки все равно необходимы?

```
@Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
    if (
        sUriMatcher.match(uri) != STUDENTS &&
        sUriMatcher.match(uri) != CLASSES
    ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values;
    if (initialValues != null) {
        values = new ContentValues(initialValues);
    }
    else {
        values = new ContentValues();
    }
    long rowId = -1;
    Uri rowUri = Uri.EMPTY;
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case STUDENTS:
            if (values.containsKey(ContractClass.Students.COLUMN_NAME_FIRST_NAME) == false) {
                values.put(ContractClass.Students.COLUMN_NAME_FIRST_NAME, "");
            }
            if (values.containsKey(ContractClass.Students.COLUMN_NAME_SECOND_NAME) == false) {
                values.put(ContractClass.Students.COLUMN_NAME_SECOND_NAME, "");
            }
            if (values.containsKey(ContractClass.Students.COLUMN_NAME_AVERAGE_SCORE) == false) {
                values.put(ContractClass.Students.COLUMN_NAME_AVERAGE_SCORE, 0.0);
            }
            if (values.containsKey(ContractClass.Students.COLUMN_NAME_FK_CLASS_ID) == false) {
                values.put(ContractClass.Students.COLUMN_NAME_FK_CLASS_ID, -1);
            }
            rowId = db.insert(ContractClass.Students.TABLE_NAME,
                ContractClass.Students.COLUMN_NAME_FIRST_NAME,
                values);
            if (rowId > 0) {
                rowUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContractClass.Students.CONTENT_ID_URI_BASE, rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(rowUri, null);
            }
        break;
        case CLASSES:
            if (values.containsKey(ContractClass.Classes.COLUMN_NAME_CLASS_NUMBER) == false) {
                values.put(ContractClass.Classes.COLUMN_NAME_CLASS_NUMBER, "");
            }
            if (values.containsKey(ContractClass.Classes.COLUMN_NAME_CLASS_LETTER) == false) {
                values.put(ContractClass.Classes.COLUMN_NAME_CLASS_LETTER, "");
            }
            rowId = db.insert(ContractClass.Classes.TABLE_NAME,
                ContractClass.Classes.COLUMN_NAME_CLASS_NUMBER,
                values);
            if (rowId > 0) {
                rowUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContractClass.Classes.CONTENT_ID_URI_BASE, rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(rowUri, null);
            }
        break;
    }
    return rowUri;
}
```